# How to list tuples of variant lengths into tables in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I hope anyone can help me.
I query different tables (with different numbers of columns) in my MySQL db to get a preview of the first 100 rows. I want to display the values in a table.
In views.py I have the following piece of code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
table_name = '%s';" %table)
columns = cursor.fetchall()
columns_list = [i[0] for i in columns]
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 100;" %table)
preview = cursor.fetchall()
```

The code in my html template looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% if columns_list %}
            {% for column in columns_list %}
                <th>{{column}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% if preview %}
            {% for row in preview %}
                <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.3 }}</td>
    </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
</table>
```

But this works only if my table has 4 columns. 
Is there an easier way to split the tuples and allocate them than using lots of for loops and arrays?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested *for* loop to dynamically generate your table columns:

```
{% if preview %}
    {% for row in preview %}
    <tr>
        {% for col in row %}
        <td>{{ col }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```